# Sending Data from Apple Watch to iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, apple-watch, watchos

I am currently using Xcode 11.1, and I have not seen this error anywhere online.

I want to be able to send data from the Apple Watch to the iPhone, so I created an app that uses sendMessage from the Apple Watch to the iPhone.

In ViewController.swift, I have

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.wcSession = WCSession.default
        self.wcSession.delegate = self
        self.wcSession.activate()
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        print(message["test"])
    }
```

And in my InterfaceController.swift, I have

```
    @IBAction func sendToPhone() {
        transferToPhone = ["test": "FROM WATCH"]
        wcSession.sendMessage(transferToPhone, replyHandler: {reply in print("done")}, errorHandler: {error in print(error.localizedDescription)})
        print("sent data over to phone")
    }
```

The error I get from this is

```
2019-10-16 17:14:39.345525+0800 sendTest WatchKit Extension[7302:293398] [WC] WCSession iOS app not installed
2019-10-16 17:14:39.348442+0800 sendTest WatchKit Extension[7302:293398] [WC] -[WCSession _onqueue_notifyOfMessageError:messageID:withErrorHandler:] (null) errorHandler: YES with WCErrorDomain:7018
Companion app is not installed.
```

However, both the iPhone and Watch app are installed. I can even send data from the iPhone to the Watch app. I currently use UpdateApplicationContext for iPhone to the Watch and SendMessage for the Watch to the iPhone.

Comment: To anyone seeing this issue in the future, this seems to be an issue with Apple's SDK. It is completely working fine on an iPhone and Apple Watch, but it does not work on their simulators as of Xcode 11.1, running iOS 13.1 and watchOS 6

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce this in Xcode 11.1 (11A1027). I recommend filing a bug report in Feedback Assistant under Developer Tools → Simulator. Make sure to run `xcrun simctl diagnose` in Terminal then attach the outputted Simulator logs to the report.

Maybe downloading the latest Xcode 11.2 beta will help as a workaround for now?

Comment: Hey, Austin! Thanks for the response. It seems to me that the problem is with the SDK since I was able to run the app just fine on my own iPhone and Apple Watch. I will definitely send a report to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Supports Running Without iOS App Installation" is checked in the WatchKit extension target of the Xcode project.
If it is checked, uncheck it.

Comment: Thanks found the checkbox under "General" > "Deployment Info", but now I have a "Cycle in dependencies between targets '###' and '### WatchKit Extension'; build could produce unreliable results...".